# Rename the overused/misused [patentability] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [[patentability](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patentability)] tag is supposed to be for questions about patentability ***law*** — i.e. Questions about what conditions must be met for a patent to be held valid. But the [patentability] tags is quickly becoming the go-to tag for any post asking about specific patents.

I suspect this is because folks try and tag their questions p-a-t-e-n-t … and this is the first thing that pops up.

I suggest renaming the [patentability] tag to disambiguate it as a "law-related" tag.

Comment: [patentability-law]?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

#### [patentability-conditions]

would be more explicit.

Comment: I fear it wouldn't be any better.

Answer (score 0):

#### [patentability-law].

This explicitly marks these questions as legal issues and interpretation of law.